# BSOD new Lenovo 14ARP8 laptop. > WinDbg Symbols downloading issue / Windows download errors (can't debug BSOD dump)

Tags: windows, bsod, lenovo-laptop, windbg

I am hoping someone here with knowledge in this area would be able to give me a helping hand. The laptop started BSODing with stock setup. I wiped it and got it set back up manually.

**In short:**
new Yoga 7 Pro 14ARP8, constant BSOD.

**Tried:**

1. Windows 11 stock w/ laptop (BSOD)
2. Install 21H2. Manual drivers installed + Win Update fully > BSOD (after it looked stable for a little while)
3. Fresh install of latest ISO from MS-manual driver install (chipset > amd > rest) + Windows Update fully > BSOD (same as before).
4. Used Vantage to install drivers. Same result.
5. Removing Firmware driver.
6. Removing the other drivers for thermal / power management.

Windows Update, manually installed drivers and lenovo vantage from fresh installs. It happens every time and I haven't been able to pinpoint. Hence, trying to debug minidumps to find the culprit.

*Had this exact issue on a previous yoga a few years back, forgot fix.*

**PS.** *I seem to be having issue downloading a lot of things on the machine (using usb-a to ethernet dongle). Even Steam, Epic or even WinDbg all stop mid download*

**Trying to debug**

1. Installed WinDbg, run app
2. Symbol path: `srv*c:\sym*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`
3. .reload

**Error**

```
Module name            Error

ntkrnlmp               The system cannot find the file specified
```

Inside 'sym' folder > C:\sym\ntkrnlmp.pdb\54C8C67BD2A54FA5BD82F1BE21CF4A3A1
This is the file I get > download90C5ABFF7F7944A98E2C2088E335CC4D.error

Any ideas?

Comment: BSODs should not happen on new Lenovo machines.  I have a new one here and a new(ish) one beside it and no BSODs.  Use the Lenovo System to update ALL drivers. test and then contact Lenovo Support for Warranty service.

Comment: Do you mean Lenovo Vantage or auto driver option via the irwebsite?

I'll do that, thanks. I got to run WinDbg properly in Safety Mode.

Comment: Either Vantage -> Update or System Update will work. Same end result.  I use both.

Comment: Try `.sympath srv*C:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.

Think I figured it out. Did a clean format and installed chipset > display driver first. Then full windows update. Still stable, so did the rest of Lenovo drivers. Stable. Opted to not install Vantage and did them manually (probably didn't make a difference, but wanted to do them slowly and test between each run to have more control). All Windows updates and still no BSOD. Did not  install Optional updates in Windows. I think it was those which caused the driver conflict. Lesson learned :)

Comment: Please read the HELP section to better understand how this site works. Answers do not go in Questions, they go down in the answer section. You do not add "(Solved)" to the title of your own question. If you answer your own question (which is awesome!) post the complete answer down in the Answer section, and then you'll be able to mark it as an answer a short time later. Keep in mind that answers should help others who have the same problem, so don't just say "It's fixed now", but include specific steps you performed to resolve the problem.

Comment: My bad. Thank you for clarifying. I added it to the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional Drivers in the Windows update advanced section were the culprit. Uninstalling them didn't solve it for me.

*Unsure which it was for me, but either the Lenovo Firmware (1.21.0.0.) or the usb-a ethernet dock*.

**This is how I solved it**

1. **Downloaded the latest ISO for Windows 11** on Microsofts website.
2. **Downloaded RUFUS** *(first google search)* and **made a bootable USB stick** *(8gb or larger, RUFUS will format it for you).*
3. **After Windows successfully installed** > **Installed drivers manually** *(but Lenovo Vantage, or their auto installer works fine too)*.
4. I chose to **install Lenovo Chipset** and **VGA driver first**.
5. **Rebooted** > did **full windows update**.
6. **Once fully updated with Windows drivers** > reboot.
7. **Install remaining Lenovo drivers**.
8. Did **not** install the Optional Windows updates.

I chose to break it up to see if any of the drivers were causing the issues.

I will do a macrium reflect backup of the machine and then try to install the firmware. If it breaks Windows again I'll revert back. Will report my findings here.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).